# Perform a task / execute script after a Bamboo build is manually stopped

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Say you have a build that executes a script somewhere and waits for it to finish. If the build is manually stopped, the script is **not**. But you want it to be killed automatically.

Is there a simple way of running a specified job (which will send a termination signal to the running script, perform a clean-up etc.) to stop the build gracefully?

No straightforward solution for this in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a "final" task in your job to terminate the running script. A final task is always run at the end of the job even if a previous job step fails or the job is manually stopped.

If the script is not running (because it has completed normally) the final task would need to be written in a way that it fails gracefully, i.e. find there is nothing to do and terminate.

Comment: Amazingly, it's true and it's that simple. Thanks!